# Angular 4 and GoldenLayout - change detection doesn't work

Tags: angular, golden-layout

I'am using Golden Layout with my app created using Angular 4 (via angular cli). Golden Layout works well. It shows up, and all components are also in place. But since my components are placed in GL, the angular change detection mechanism stopped working. 
Have anyone had such problems?